# Find file in sub directory

Tags: vba, file, subdirectory

I need to do a code in VBA to find a file in a subdirectory.

With the code from 'brettdj' in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) I can find the file if I specify the full directory

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
    file = Dir("\\A\B\C\D\")
    While (file <> "")
        If InStr(file, "701000034955") > 0 Then
            MsgBox "found " & file
            Exit Sub
        End If
    file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```

I'm looking for a why to not to have to specify the full directory.

I tried the code in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddA2_SOaq14), but I get a 'type mistmatch' error message in the last line

```
Sub Find_Files()       
    f = "\\A\B\"        
    ibox = "701000034955"        
    sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & f & ibox & """ /s /a /b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)         
    Sheets("Sheet1").[A1].Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = Application.Transpose(sn) ' I get an error message in this line    
End Sub
```

Any ideas on why the code above is not working and if there is a better solution to search in subfolders for a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second code differs from the first one in that this latter searches for any file in given folder (and subfolders) whose name is exactly *"701000034955"* while the former searches for file whose name *contains* that string

hence I guess you just have to use some wildchars

```
ibox = "*701000034955*" 
sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & f & Application.PathSeparator & ibox & """ /s /a /b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
Sheets("Sheet1").[A1].Resize(UBound(sn)) = Application.Transpose(sn)
```

note the resizing is `UBound(sn)` instead of `UBound(sn) + 1` since there's one ending`vbCrlf` generating an empty entry in the last position of `sn`

Answer (score 1):

For the bottom one don't forget to fully qualify the file name with its extension and consider using Path separator to concatenate. For example:

```
Sub Find_Files()

    Dim f As String

    f = ThisWorkbook.Path
    ibox = "701000034955.xlsb"
    sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & f & Application.PathSeparator & ibox & """ /s /a /b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
    Sheets("Sheet1").[A1].Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = Application.Transpose(sn)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr. I still get the same error in the last line

Comment: When you have the error, what do you get in the immediate window if you put ?f & Application.PathSeparator & ibox   and hit enter?